# Is it いる or ある with 物の怪? (Are ghosts animate or inanimate?)

Tags: animacy

Shall we treat [物の怪]{もののけ} (a kind of ghost) as animate or inanimate? Does it vary for the different ghosts?

Comment: Animacy in linguistic sense basically means if it can move by itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can say "物の怪がいる", we don't use ある at all with 物の怪, 幽霊, 妖怪, お化け, and so on. So I guess we treat them as animate.

Answer (score 3):

If you do a google search for 幽霊{ゆうれい} and ある you will find many hits with "いる” instead.